# npm hangs when called in Visual Studio prebuild events

Tags: npm, webpack, visual-studio-2017, pre-build-event

Why when running the commands below in the cmd (and the current directory being the root of my visual studio project), everything is okay :

```
npm install
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
webpack
```

But when asking to run that in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 with Visual Studio 2017 it hangs on the first line (while it does not require any user input).When I am saying it hangs, it hangs for about 3-5min (after executing the last line using call), like doing literally.

I managed to get a bit further by using call on each of them (which is suggested by the MS documentation for calling .bat scripts):

```
call npm install
call webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
call webpack
```

For some reasons it works and hangs only on the last line.

When trying out something simple like `echo there` everything is fine, I don't really get what is wrong with the lines above.

[EDIT]
ALready checked that out [npm hangs on any command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388730/npm-hangs-on-any-command)

But my issue seems to be different since it can run cmd and PowerShell (but hangs whenever it is run in an ISE PowerShell tab...)

Comment: Hi. Have you solved this?

Comment: Kinda, but don't remember how, pass 3 months and my brain starts to flush pretty much everything ;-) plus I've stopped using VS, I am a fervent defender of VS Code and Rider now.
Are you facing this issue @Monochromie right now?

Comment: Yeah. My problem is in proxy settings in .npmrc file. When I disable it - everything is fine

Comment: I had the same issue. A workaround is to call a bat file in the prebuild step, the bat file uses this 'Msbuild.exe ".\my.proj", then the proj file uses exec to call the comment. I don't know why this works and the other doesn't and it's a hack so I didn't add this as an answer