# What is the issue "node" is working but "nodemon" is not woking on windows 7 64-bit in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js. `node` is working fine but when I installed the `nodemon` package, it gives an error: `exception in nodemon killing node`, even when installed globally.

```
 22 Jun 13:07:29 - [nodemon] v1.3.7
 22 Jun 13:07:29 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
 22 Jun 13:07:29 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
 22 Jun 13:07:29 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
 exception in nodemon killing node  
 Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
 at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
 at child_process.js:1144:20
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

 ---------------------------------------------------------- 
 If appropriate, please file an error with the output from:
 $ node                     
 C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.
 js server.js --dump
 At http://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/new
```

Answer (score 8):

Possible solutions.

**1. Permissions**

The problem may be in your file permissions. Execute in git bash or from windows to give full permission to the project folder.

```
$ chmod -R 777 [folder]
```

**2. Environment Variables**

Missing "C:\Windows\System32" in the PATH.

[Github issue](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/616)

**3. Reinstall**

Altogether remove nodemon using npm and try reinstalling.

```
npm uninstall -g nodemon
```

**4. Update nodejs**

If you have an old version of NodeJS, try updating it. I prefer entirely removing NodeJS and reinstalling it again.

[Step by steps to remove NodeJS in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

Note: Your question may not be rich enough to answer correctly. Please include more information about questions if those didn't work.

Comment: after unintentional clearing my Windows PATH Variable, the System32 Path was missing. after adding it the spawn cmd error was gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Help spawn to locate your nodemon.cmd like this:

```
var nodemonCmd = (process.platform == 'win32') ? 'node_modules\\.bin\\nodemon.cmd' : 'nodemon'
myApp = spawn(nodemonCmd, ['build/server.bundle']);
```

Hope it works :)