# Nodemon running express error

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I'm learning express, and I'm running this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>');
});

app.get('/api', function(req,res) {
    res.json({ firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe'})
});

app.listen(port);
```

When I try to execute it like this, it works:

```
node app.js
```

But when I try to run it this way:

```
nodemon app.js
```

This happens:

```
[nodemon] 1.8.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: check this out https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/504 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974833/what-is-the-issue-node-is-working-but-nodemon-is-not-woking-on-windows-7-64 most of people had C:\Windows\System32\ missing in the PATH and ya plz check if all packages are installed

Comment: What do you mean "missing in the PATH?", all the packages are installed. I can run the application with node command.

Comment: Have you checked the system environment variables path. This may help you.You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624686/get-spawn-cmd-enoent-when-try-to-build-cordova-application-event-js85

Comment: Thanks Ketha! It's working now! :D

Answer (score 0):

Please restart your computer and try it again.
In my case it helped.