# I cant start nodemon on my windows 10

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, nodemon

I started learning Node recently, I successfully ran my first node app, though without nodemon. I installed nodemon globally using `npm install -g nodemon`, and it successfully installed..
If I then run `nodemon index` i see the following errors

`[nodemon] 1.12.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter`rs
``` [nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting ``node index index.js ```
`events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`
      `^`

```
`Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:192:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:374:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

`
Please your suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Its not a depulicate of that question, that question did not resolve my problem, but the solutions given by @Jackowski solved my problem

Comment: then you clearly missed where the question had the exact error code. and the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34083398/1657476) that explicitly mentions the PATH missing the System32 folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your PATH variables include: `C:\Windows\System32\`. If not, add it.

Comment: Thanks alot, this solved my problem and Nodemon is now running perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Its a Path Issue

**1.** Add `C:\Windows\System32\` to the PATH Environment variable at the end of line

also

```
**`Verify the npm folder exists at the following location    C:\Users\My-UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm`** 

Try to run npm cache clean
```

Comment: thanks alot, this solved my problem