# Error: Cannot find module 'npm-registry-client'

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I try to install npm-registry-client, I get the error "*Error: Cannot find module 'npm-registry-client'*".

I have tried to solve this with the following commands, but this did not work:

`npm uninstall`

`npm install -g npm@latest`

The full output is:

```
user@pc ~/devel> npm install npm-registry-client --save

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npm-registry-client'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/caching-client.js:9:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

*Getting the above on every npm procedure I tried so far. It appeared after updating npm*

Comment: That's because I typoed npm to nom, try again? :(

Comment: haha nice. No still not working :) Same error.

Comment: Maybe I need to do some digging somewhere else. i am trying to setup an yeoman angular fullstack app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Official Joyent Docs are outdated

We need to ditch tldr mentality for this one and get [lastest information about setup_x.x](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories) before contintuing.

## Piping curl setup_x.x to bash fails

Furthermore [official Joyent Docs](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager?utm_source=[deliciuos]&utm_medium=twitter) use `curl` and pipe to `bash -E`, which fails for me. Hence we are going to use wget.

#### Apt-get the lastest node package

After reading above paragraphs, you can now follow this:

```
sudo apt-get remove node npm nodejs -y
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules  
sudo wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12
sudo -E bash ./setup_0.12
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
sudo npm -g install npm@latest
```

`nodejs --version` now should print latest one, e.g.

`v0.12.9`

## Compile from Source

If nothing helps, as in my case, you want to go oldschool and compile from source:

```
sudo apt-get remove node npm nodejs -y
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
mkdir ~/node && cd ~/node
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.9/node-v0.12.9.tar.gz
tar -xzvf node-v0.12.9.tar.gz
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be a bug  in npm@3.4.1. you should try upgrading from npm@3.3.6 directly to npm@next, which will bypass the buggy versions of npm. If you're currently stuck with a broken npm, and you can get back to a working npm by reinstalling Node.js.

The best way to jump over this problem is to reinstall Node using an official Node installer (not Homebrew) and use the packaged npm to upgrade straight to npm@next.

To reinstall Node.js:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

## Using Ubuntu

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

## Using Debian, as root

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: following your tip on ubuntu 15.10 I get: "/usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file"... this is actually two commands so 2nd sudo starts a new command!

Comment: @mark u r right , actually i paste this stuff and didn't notice that it printed in same line, Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @NaveenSingh what's your source for your statement: `seems to be a bug in npm@3.4.1`? I want to explore more about my alternatives, since 3.4.1 is currently the latest stable released.

Comment: @JesperRønn-Jensen it's mentioned on github issues by npm owner (othiym23). You can check this on  https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10492 in very first comment of owner

Comment: Info is outdated. setup_5.x will install legacy node. next time you copy paste please read before. `NOTE: Temporary info before full update of this wiki page` Downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

I believe npm-registry-client is a separate package.

Have you tried `npm install npm-registry-client --save` ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-registry-client

edit: It looks like your npm is just plain broke.

Maybe these steps will help:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: `module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npm-registry-client'` It's what i am getting with every other npm operation I tried so far as well.

Comment: This is on the npm install command? Can you edit your post to include the full error block?

Comment: after running the command you provided, the "ng add angular-bootstrap-md" command was ok.

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem. I'm using Ubuntu.
Steps that I've done:

1. deleted folder `/usr/lib/node_modules`
2. reinstalled nodejs using this help [nodejs](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)
3. updated npm to latest stable using `sudo npm update -g npm`

Basicly you have to reinstall nodejs :( Nothing else helped.
P.S. just in case: save somewhere list of packages which you need, just listing node_modules folder(`ls -l /usr/lib/node_modules`) and saving output. So you can reinstall them later.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I am still getring the same error message even after following these steps.

Comment: What OS do you use? You reinstalled using tips from nodejs team(link that I gave)? What wersion of nodejs you installed?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. I have node from main repo. I tried your repo but curl gives errors, I would like to stay on offficial node release, no?

Comment: And you will stay on official node branch: 4.x - LTS branch, 5.x - latest stable. Ubuntus' packages are little outdated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Windows and found that the node uninstaller left the cache in place in AppData/Roaming.

This worked for me:

1. Uninstall Node
2. Remove npm and cache by hand
3. Reinstall from the msi on the official Nodejs website

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem just by using npm 3.5.0

```
sudo npm install -g npm@3.5.0
```

I had this problem when I tried to install atom-editor on archlinux from AUR repository with npm 3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same issue while working with Protractor tool. What I did was that I tried to update `npm 3.4.1` to latest(this being the latest),  and did it twice with below command twice:

```
npm install -g npm
```

So, something went wrong in the `npm 3.4.1` and the above error kept coming.

Some issues add for this on github: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10492, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10394 and https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2528.

**Solution is to Reinstall the Nodejs by removing all the file associated with it.**

Make sure you:

1. Restart the machine after uninstalling the nodejs.
2. Delete the following files if not already done:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs
   C:\Program Files\Nodejs
   C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (or %appdata%\npm)
   C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (or %appdata%\npm-cache)
   ```
3. Install using the node installer.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/3619412

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my mac and the solution for me was uninstall my node.js and npm modules following the steps from this [link](http://benznext.com/completely-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-os-x/):

1. go to **/usr/local/lib** and delete any node and node_modules
2. go to **/usr/local/include** and delete any node and node_modules directory
3. if you installed with **brew install node**, then run **brew uninstall node**
   in your terminal
4. check your **Home** directory for any local or lib or include folders,
   and delete any node or node_modules from there
5. go to **/usr/local/bin** and delete any node executable

Also I did this:

1. sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm
2. sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.*
3. sudo rm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
4. sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
5. sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
6. sudo rm /opt/local/bin/node
7. sudo rm /opt/local/include/node
8. sudo rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules

Then I reinstalled a clean version of node.js.  In my case is the version 5.1.0 which I downloaded from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. Removing the entire `node_modules` folder and re-installing worked for me. Hope it will help you.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and worked

```
npm cache clean --force
npm -g install npm
npm -g install npm-registry-client
```