# Later version of Node.js is already installed. Setup will now exit

Tags: node.js

I am having this error when I run Node.js v4.2.3 installer. I previously had Node.js v5.2.0 stable. I decided to go to lower version for some reason. I completely removed Node.js v5.2.0 completely as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows).

Now when I run the installer for v4.2.3, it says I have later version installed already. But no signs and trace of node in my computer.

Any ideas what else I might have missed? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should try to reinstall node v5.2.0 then using [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) to manage node version

Comment: which operating system is this? Linux?

Comment: They're using Windows, so `n` wouldn't work out of the box since it's a giant bash script.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1

Comment: Has anyone here encountered this problem? This only means I still have node.js in my computer. I want it to be removed completely.

Comment: if you are going to really switch between different node.js version i would recommend using nvm. Its an handy tool for such jobs.