# How to fix node.js File upload ENOENT error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
module.exports.uploader=function(fileobj){
 fileobj.mv('./127.0.0.1:3000/uploadedImage',function(error){
        console.log(error);
 });
}
```

This is the error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'D:\programming\bnl\127.0.0.1:3000\css'
>       at Error (native)

Comment: you are using a node filesystem function to move file from a web address location

Comment: I'm guessing that the `127.0.0.1:3000` directory doesn't exist - try creating it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't understand it wrong, you're trying to move the **fileobj** to the **uploadedImage** folder, right?

You shouldn't pass the host as a path. This is why you're getting the error.

Try to put the path to the uploadedImage folder relative to your project folder. Something like this:

```js
module.exports.uploader = function(fileobj){
 fileobj.mv(_dirname + '/path/to/uploadedImage', function(error){
  console.log(error);
 });
}
```

Comment: what is '_dirname' ?

Comment: Your project directory name. Is /uploadedImage inside it?

Comment: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'D:\programming\bnl\uploadedImage'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\programming\\bnl\\uploadedImage'

Comment: Take a look at this right here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a