# Can't Install Youtube Video Player plugin in Ionic 3

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I tried many times and I also googled but in vain, I think it is a problem of stability of ionic!

When I run:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Glitchbone/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer.git
```

I get this error:

> Error: Failed to fetch plugin
>   https://github.com/Glitchbone/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer.git via
>   registry.
>
> Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
>
> Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963228 Error output:
>   npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\Houssem\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3196-5b6372b9\git-cache-721c1a29\765b5954e78ecf7950099c10bfe5f81133f8f396
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "https://github.com/Glitchbone/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer.git" "--save"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.10.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>   npm ERR! code EISDIR
>   npm ERR! errno -4068
>   npm ERR! syscall read
>
> npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
>   npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>   npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
>
> npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     F:\WORK\EBOOK\ebookmuhammed\node_modules\npm-debug.log

Having that:

```
cordova --version  => 7.0.1
ionic --version    => 3.9.2
npm --version      => 3.10.10
```

Comment: It's trying to read a directory as a file. There are too many suggestions here to recommend anything, but I'd look at these answers  and see if any of that resolves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a

Comment: Thanks but that is not helping

Answer (score 1):

Well, what does the error message say:

> npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR! eisdir and is related to **npm not being able to find a package.json** in

Since cordova 7.0.0 cordova-plugins need a `package.json` file ([Cordova 7.0.0 release notes](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html)). So fork the plugin add a `package.json` file copy the contents of a package.json file of another plugin and replace the values with ones that fit the plugin (`plugin.xml` is a good place for copying).

Comment: I'll see that way asap