# EISDIR error with "Cordova crypt file plugin"

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application built using **ionic V1**. Everything was working fine until recently. Now this **EISDIR** error keeps popping up whenever I try to build it. After a lot of debugging, I found out that **cordova-plugin-crypt-file** was causing the issue. Because when I disable it, the project successfully Builds.

I am using [**Cordova crypt file plugin**](https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file) to encrypt my source code. I spent a lot of time trying to fix it, but sadly I couldn't do anything.

I also know that EISDIR error is due to directory issue ("Error, Is Directory") from [NPM stuck giving the same error EISDIR: Illegal operation on a directory, read at error (native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a#answer-42677294). But I could not find any directory issues in my project.

Also, I have seen this issue on github https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file/issues/39. As suggested in the question when I comment the problematic line. Everything is ok and the project Builds.

I am not sure how to debug this. Any help would be appreciated. Since the client suggested this plugin, I have been actively searching for a way to fix this. But could not find any solutions yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this error myself.

The plugin gives a console log when it successfully completes encrypting a file.

I had no way to find out which file it was encrypting now (which caused the error). When I looked into the plugin files, it had a hook file called 'after_prepare.js', which console logs the files it has successfully encrypted. I then added a console log before the file encryption process start, and I was able to track down which file was causing the issue.

```
}).forEach(function(file) {
        console.log('file', file); // console log I added
        var content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8');
        fs.writeFileSync(file, encryptData(content, key, iv), 'utf-8');
        console.log('encrypt: ' + file);
    });
```

Seems it was a directory name issue. I had Chart.js installed and one of its folders was named **chart.js** which was causing the issue.