# Error is: Command npm install failed with exit code 235

Tags: android, build, angular2-nativescript

Trying to build a release version for android.

I'm getting this error:
Unable to install dependencies. Make sure your package.json is valid and all dependencies are correct. Error is: Command npm install failed with exit code 235

the npm-debug.log file contains.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly install normalizeTree
8 silly loadCurrentTree Finishing
9 silly loadIdealTree Starting
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly cloneCurrentTree Starting
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 silly cloneCurrentTree Finishing
14 silly loadShrinkwrap Starting
15 silly install loadShrinkwrap
16 silly loadShrinkwrap Finishing
17 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
18 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
19 silly fetchOtherPackageData nativescript-ng2-carousel@file:..
20 silly cache add args [ 'nativescript-ng2-carousel@file:..', null ]
21 verbose cache add spec nativescript-ng2-carousel@file:..
22 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
22 silly cache add   raw: 'nativescript-ng2-carousel@file:..',
22 silly cache add   scope: null,
22 silly cache add   escapedName: 'nativescript-ng2-carousel',
22 silly cache add   name: 'nativescript-ng2-carousel',
22 silly cache add   rawSpec: 'file:..',
22 silly cache add   spec: '/Mobile/NativeScript-Projects',
22 silly cache add   type: 'local' }
23 error addLocal Could not install /Mobile/NativeScript-Projects
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native)
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for nativescript-ng2-carousel@file:.. { Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native) errno: -21, code: 'EISDIR', syscall: 'read' }
25 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
27 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
28 silly install printInstalled
29 verbose stack Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
29 verbose stack     at Error (native)
30 verbose cwd /Mobile/NativeScript-Projects/Genkan
31 error Darwin 17.4.0
32 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
33 error node v6.11.0
34 error npm  v3.10.10
35 error code EISDIR
36 error errno -21
37 error syscall read
38 error eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
39 error eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
39 error eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
39 error eisdir a package you are trying to install.
40 verbose exit [ -21, true ]
```

the package.json file in the root folder of the project is

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
   "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",     
   "readme": "NativeScript Application",
   "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
   "nativescript": {
     "id": "com.genkan.mobileapp",
     "tns-android": {
       "version": "3.4.2"
     },
     "tns-ios": {
       "version": "3.4.1"
     }
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "@angular/animations": "~4.0.0",
     "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
     "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
     "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
     "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
     "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
     "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
     "angular2-tooltip": "^3.1.0",
     "email-validator": "^1.1.1",
     "nativescript-angular": "~3.0.0",
     "nativescript-angular-snapshot": "3.0.0-5.5.372.32",
     "nativescript-background-http": "^3.1.0",
     "nativescript-camera": "^3.1.4",
     "nativescript-couchbase": "^1.0.18",
     "nativescript-drop-down": "^3.1.1",
     "nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
     "nativescript-geolocation": "^3.0.1",
     "nativescript-imagepicker": "^5.0.1",
     "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.1.0",
     "nativescript-ng2-carousel": "file:..",
     "nativescript-orientation": "^2.1.0",
     "nativescript-phone": "^1.3.1",
     "nativescript-screen-orientation": "^2.0.0",
     "nativescript-social-share": "^1.3.2",
     "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
     "nativescript-tooltip": "^2.1.2",
     "nativescript-ui-listview": "^3.5.1",
     "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^3.5.1",
     "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
     "rxjs": "~5.2.0",
     "tns-core-modules": "^3.4.1",
     "zone.js": "0.8.2"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.0",
     "@ngtools/webpack": "~1.9.4",
     "babel-traverse": "6.25.0",
     "babel-types": "6.25.0",
     "babylon": "6.17.4",
     "copy-webpack-plugin": "~4.3.0",
     "css-loader": "~0.28.7",
     "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.2",
     "lazy": "1.0.11",
     "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
     "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.4.0",
     "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.9.2",
     "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.8.1",
     "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
     "resolve-url-loader": "~2.2.1",
     "tns-platform-declarations": "^3.3.0",
     "typescript": "~2.2.1",
     "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "~1.1.6",
     "webpack": "~3.10.0",
     "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.1",
     "webpack-sources": "~1.1.0"
   }
 }
```

Can anyone tell me what part of the package.json could be wrong?

Edit: This started after running

```
npm install --save-dev nativescript-dev-webpack
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a

Comment: I've looked at that link, and i see that the error is due to trying to access a file, but its actually a directory.

This line:
23 error addLocal Could not install /Mobile/NativeScript-Projects
is pointing to the directory that contains the root project folder.

I just don't know where it would be getting that from.