# EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read + Nodemailer image attachment

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, loopback

I just wanted to know how to specify the path in attachments in Nodemailer. I am getting this above-mentioned error. Can anyone specify how to specify the path?

`var imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/images/')`

`attachments : [{
              filename: "Header@3x.png",
              path:`${imagePath}`,
              cid: 'headerImage'
          }]`

Comment: Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42677294/5452965) out. Are you sure that `imagePath` variable contains the correct path to the image ?

Comment: Yeah, I consoled it. It is the exact path where images are stored.

Comment: Yes but you need to provide the full path to the image, not only the directory. I mean `path/to/image/directory` is wrong and `path/to/image/directory/image.extension` is correct

Comment: But I am already specifying the filename. ok, let me try this way.

Comment: Thanks @codtex It worked. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: You are welcome friend

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM stuck giving the same error EISDIR: Illegal operation on a directory, read at error (native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. But I resolved by giving the full path till Image.

**For example:**

```
var imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '/images/Header@3x.png'); // In this line, Give the full path of image.
attachments : [{
              filename: "Header@3x.png",
              path:${imagePath},         // __dirname+'/images/Header@3x.png'
              cid: 'headerImage'
}]
```

**And your HTML will be :**

```
<div>
   <img src="cid:headerImage" alt="Header Image" width="100" height="100"/>
</div>
```

( In the path IMAGE_NAME is important and required.)