# How to upload image to Google Cloud with multer node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, google-cloud-platform, multer

I have done upload using Multer in NodeJS if storage is memoryStorage, since file is save in buffer first, and than from buffer I can upload to Google Drive,

But if using memoryStorage I can not rename image file,

I using multer.diskStorage but when I post, file is succeed upload but not the picture, file size become small like 10B.

this is my code in helper with function uploadImage

```
const util = require('util')
const gc = require('../config/')
const bucket = gc.bucket('jsimage')//bucket name

const { format } = util

const uploadImage = (file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log(file);
  //const { originalname, buffer } = file
  const { filename, destination } = file

  //const blob = bucket.file(originalname.replace(/ /g, "_"))
  const blob = bucket.file(filename)
  const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
    resumable: false
  })

  blobStream.on('finish', () => {
    const publicUrl = format(
      `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
    )
    resolve(publicUrl)
  })
  .on('error', () => {
    reject(`Unable to upload image, something went wrong`)
  })
  //.end(buffer)
  .end(destination)

})

module.exports = uploadImage
```

with code above I succeed to upload in Google Drive but not the picture, since size is always 10B.

Comment: multer has no size limit but has a field limit https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/562

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529947/how-to-upload-images-to-gcs-bucket-with-multer-and-nodejs

Comment: look like multer can not read folder of image he has to upload, but i already mention in /uploads, but still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this example, after the picture is uploaded to temp or any local folder, we can upload it to google cloud.

```
const util = require('util')
const gc = require('../config/')
const bucket = gc.bucket('jsimage')//bucket name di google drive
const path = require('path')

const { format } = util

// promises are built right away, so there's no need for then to resolve and catch for errors
const uploadImage = (file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  //console.log(file);
  const {filename} = file;
  const picture = path.join(__dirname,'../uploads/',filename);

  // This is the upload command
  bucket.upload(picture);

  // This is sent to return
  const publicUrl = format(
    `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${filename}`
  )

  resolve(publicUrl)

  reject(err=>(err))

})

module.exports = uploadImage
```