# Azure DevOps, AppCenter Distribute fails for iOS native ap

Tags: azure-devops, xcodebuild, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am trying to publish an IPA to App Center, the YAML for my build definition is the following :

```
# Xcode
# Build, test, and archive an Xcode workspace on macOS.
# Add steps that install certificates, test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xcode

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-10.13'

trigger: none

variables:
  - name: SDK
    value: iphoneos
  - name: Configuration
    value: ReleasePPD

steps:
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: 'AuraApp.xcworkspace'
- task: CocoaPods@0
  inputs:
    forceRepoUpdate: false
  displayName: 'pod install using the CocoaPods task'

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'ios_distribution.p12'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles' # Options: secureFiles, sourceRepository
    provProfileSecureFile: 'Aura_PPD_Distribution_Profile.mobileprovision'
    removeProfile: true

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    xcWorkspacePath: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/AuraApp.xcworkspace'
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: $(SDK)
    configuration: $(Configuration)
    xcodeVersion: '10' # Options: 8, 9, 10, default, specifyPath
    exportPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/PPD'
    packageApp: true
    #exportMethod: 'package'
    exportOptions: 'auto'
    #exportOptionsPlist: ''
    scheme: 'Aura PPD'
    signingOption: manual
    signingIdentity: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
    provisioningProfileUuid: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)

- task: AppCenterDistribute@1
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'Azure App Center'
    appSlug: aurafoundation/Aura
    appFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.ipa
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'Test'
```

The Xcode build task seems to be working well :

```
##[debug]exec tool: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   -exportArchive
##[debug]   -archivePath
##[debug]   /Users/vsts/agent/2.146.0/work/1/s/Aura PPD.xcarchive
##[debug]   -exportPath
##[debug]   /Users/vsts/agent/2.146.0/work/1/a/PPD
##[debug]   -exportOptionsPlist
##[debug]   _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
[command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Users/vsts/agent/2.146.0/work/1/s/Aura PPD.xcarchive -exportPath /Users/vsts/agent/2.146.0/work/1/a/PPD -exportOptionsPlist _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/xcpretty --no-color
2019-02-12 11:03:58.404 xcodebuild[1595:20747] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/Aura PPD_2019-02-12_11-03-58.402.xcdistributionlogs'.
▸ Export Succeeded
##[debug]success of first tool:true
##[debug]rc:0
##[debug]success:true
##[debug]task result: Succeeded
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]Xcode task execution completed with no errors.
##[debug]Agent.Version=2.146.0
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=TaskHub;feature=Xcode]{"xcodeVersionSelection":"10","actions":["build"],"packageApp":true,"xcodeVersion":"10.1","signingOption":"manual","exportOptions":"auto"}
##[section]Finishing: Xcode
```

The resulting IPA file shoud be located in /Users/vsts/agent/2.146.0/work/1/a/PPD according to the -exportPath parameter.

BUT ! The AppCenterDistribute step fails :

```
##[section]Starting: AppCenterDistribute
==============================================================================
Task         : App Center Distribute
Description  : Distribute app builds to testers and users via App Center
Version      : 1.147.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : For help with this task, visit the Visual Studio App Center [support site](https://aka.ms/appcentersupport/).
==============================================================================
##[error]Error: Cannot find any file based on /Users/vsts/agent/2.146.0/work/1/a/**/*.ipa.
##[section]Finishing: AppCenterDistribute
```

So the question is : where is my .ipa located ? Why can't I find my .ipa in the exportPath ?

EDIT :

I changed the exportPath parameter to specify a full path : Users/vsts/agent/2.146.0/work/1/a/PPD/Aura.ipa

Now i get another error on the AppCenter Distribute task :

```
##[debug]found 1 paths
##[debug]applying include pattern
##[debug]1 matches
##[debug]1 final results
##[debug]....... selectedPaths: /Users/vsts/agent/2.146.0/work/1/s
##[debug]....... uniquePaths:   /Users/vsts/agent/2.146.0/work/1/s
##[debug]-- Prepare symbols
##[debug]-- Prepare for uploading release.
##[debug]---- url: https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/aurafoundation/Aura/release_uploads
##[debug]---- "{\"upload_id\":\"a349d7a0-10f2-0137-9dfa-12f79a9ee306\",\"upload_url\":\"https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/sonoma/apps/a761af0d-7844-46a9-bf7b-701fa1db6b9c/app_versions/upload?upload_id=a349d7a0-10f2-0137-9dfa-12f79a9ee306\"}"
##[debug]---- http call status code: 201
##[debug]-- Uploading release...
##[debug]---- url: https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/sonoma/apps/a761af0d-7844-46a9-bf7b-701fa1db6b9c/app_versions/upload?upload_id=a349d7a0-10f2-0137-9dfa-12f79a9ee306
##[debug]---- Failed with error: Error: form-data: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Error: form-data: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: form-data: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: form-data: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
##[section]Finishing: AppCenterDistribute
```

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: Possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a for EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory