# `npm install` not working. Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: node.js, macos, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I am developing an **ionic 3** app. I developed it on **windows 10** and everything was fine. But now I shift my work **windows to mac**. 
Now problem is when i run `npm install` command on mac, then it's not working. It shows `Unhandled rejection Error`. Full errors are given below.

> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/11/85'
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/9c/8c'
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/c8/4b'
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/7c/dc'
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/6c/ff'
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/63/ae'
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/b4/ba'
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/61/df'
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/a7/af'
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory,
>   open '/Users/softograph/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/59/b7'
>
> npm ERR! cb() never called!
>
> npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error
>   at: npm ERR!     https://npm.community
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/softograph/.npm/_logs/2019-03-20T05_55_54_280Z-debug.log

**Environment Configuration**

```
Node: v8.9.3

npm: 6.7.0
```

**My Log file is**

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose npm-session aa41030c4bd27115
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall azmaeen@0.0.1
7 info lifecycle azmaeen@0.0.1~preinstall: azmaeen@0.0.1
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 12ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 1ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 5ms
16 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
17 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fanimations 125ms (from cache)
18 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic%2fapp-scripts 136ms (from cache)
19 silly pacote range manifest for @angular/animations@^5.2.9 fetched in 143ms
20 silly pacote version manifest for @ionic/app-scripts@3.1.8 fetched in 156ms
21 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2fcore 10ms (from cache)
22 silly pacote version manifest for @ionic-native/core@4.4.0 fetched in 13ms
23 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2fdevice 3ms (from cache)
24 silly pacote range manifest for @ionic-native/device@^4.6.0 fetched in 5ms
25 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2ffcm 4ms (from cache)
26 silly pacote range manifest for @ionic-native/fcm@^4.7.0 fetched in 6ms
27 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2flocal-notifications 9ms (from cache)
28 silly pacote range manifest for @ionic-native/local-notifications@^4.7.0 fetched in 12ms
29 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2fnetwork 3ms (from cache)
30 silly pacote range manifest for @ionic-native/network@^4.6.0 fetched in 4ms
31 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2fscreen-orientation 4ms (from cache)
32 silly pacote range manifest for @ionic-native/screen-orientation@^4.7.0 fetched in 6ms
33 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2fsocial-sharing 3ms (from cache)
34 silly pacote range manifest for @ionic-native/social-sharing@^4.7.0 fetched in 5ms
35 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2fsplash-screen 3ms (from cache)
36 silly pacote version manifest for @ionic-native/splash-screen@4.4.0 fetched in 4ms
37 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2fstatus-bar 3ms (from cache)
38 silly pacote version manifest for @ionic-native/status-bar@4.4.0 fetched in 4ms
39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2fstripe 3ms (from cache)
40 silly pacote range manifest for @ionic-native/stripe@^4.7.0 fetched in 4ms
41 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2funique-device-id 3ms (from cache)
42 silly pacote range manifest for @ionic-native/unique-device-id@^4.6.0 fetched in 4ms
43 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms 370ms (from cache)
44 silly pacote version manifest for @angular/forms@5.0.3 fetched in 405ms
45 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler 420ms (from cache)
46 silly pacote version manifest for @angular/compiler@5.0.3 fetched in 426ms
47 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser 434ms (from cache)
48 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore 440ms (from cache)
49 silly pacote version manifest for @angular/platform-browser@5.0.3 fetched in 442ms
50 silly pacote version manifest for @angular/core@5.0.3 fetched in 446ms
51 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler-cli 455ms (from cache)
52 silly pacote version manifest for @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.3 fetched in 461ms
53 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fhttp 463ms (from cache)
54 silly pacote version manifest for @angular/http@5.0.3 fetched in 467ms
55 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android 145ms (from cache)
56 silly pacote version manifest for cordova-android@7.0.0 fetched in 161ms
57 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-fcm 144ms (from cache)
58 silly pacote range manifest for cordova-plugin-fcm@^2.1.2 fetched in 145ms
59 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 136ms (from cache)
60 silly pacote range manifest for cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@^1.1.19 fetched in 139ms
61 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon 626ms (from cache)
62 silly pacote version manifest for @angular/common@5.0.3 fetched in 629ms
63 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic 564ms (from cache)
```

***Thanks Everyone***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM stuck giving the same error EISDIR: Illegal operation on a directory, read at error (native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a)

Comment: @VivekMolkar I have tried this answers but not working for me.

Comment: try : sudo nano npmrc

Comment: I have tried. nano opened page blank :(

Comment: @AmanullahAman have found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy `.npm` from windows to macOS?
Maybe you can try to remove the problematic directory and then run npm install again. Something like

```
$ rm -rf /Users/softograph/.npm/
```

OR it might be permission problem. You actually should never use `sudo` with `npm`. I suggest you try to use `nvm` (node version manager) and it will install node and npm for you. With nvm, you will **never** need `sudo`.

Comment: No, I didn’t copy it from Windows.

Comment: @AmanullahAman how did you run `npm install`? did you run it with a normal user? I suggest you install `nvm` (a node version manager) and use `node` and `npm` from `nvm`. Maybe you have permission problem right now.