# NPM error when installing globally to create-react-app. Trying to make a boilerplate app but gets errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, failed-installation

I am new to `react-native` and whenever I try to write a command relating to `npm`, it returns an error (usually one that says `EISDIR`). I have tried looking at the answers to similar questions of mine, but am confused by the jargon about `PATHS` and issues with directories.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `node`, and still when inputting `npx create-react-app my-app` it returns something along the lines of this:

```
npm ERR! code EISDIR


npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! errno -21

npm ERR! EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!    
/Users/username/.npm/_logs/2021-08-03T20_29_31_976Z-debug.log
username@MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Can someone explain a solution in a simple way for this? Please ask questions for more information if I left something out.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a This seems relevant.

Comment: I saw that question and tried all the solutions only to receive the same error :/