# react native expo debugger-ui Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: react-native, expo

I started a new app using expo
but when I try to open the debugger-ui
with cmd-d and click on debug remote js
I've got this ugly message:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:720:3)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:430:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:476:19)
    at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage (/Users/me/my/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:304:17)
    at new UnableToResolveError (/Users/me/my/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:290:35)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/me/my/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:168:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/me/my/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:353:43)
    at /Users/me/my/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:271:42
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/me/my/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:842:41)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

I tried googling but none of the solution works
Any idea to fix it?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42677294/5557220)?

Comment: For both iOS & Android?

Comment: I don't have option to test iOS at the moment, so it's only Android for me. (API 29, Android 10.0, Pixel 5 emulated device).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a React-native issue; the error is linked to the metro dependencies inside node_modules.

The EISDIR error is likely to be a misreported error due to a bug in metro that has been fixed in metro 0.65.

Some methods of troubleshooting can be found [here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/991).

Comment: Looks like this is as close as we're going to get to the answer. Linked thread contains possible ways to debug the error and a few suggestions how to fix it. It seems that error does not affect the functionality and hopefully will be fixed in newer react-native versions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled the Expo Go app from my phone, and then downloaded & installed it again, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem while I was changing some npm settings. I did a mistake with one `npm config set` command and this added a line referring to a non-existing directory to `C:\Users\{User}\.npmrc`. After I deleted that line manually from `.npmrc`, the problem was gone.

Comment: I have no file .npmrc at this location and I do not recall doing operations with npm config set. However I've seen some posts from people on other websites which mentioned this solution, so I guess it's worth trying.

Comment: Please mention that you have copy-pasted this answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35429397/1624844