# Docker getting error FATAL EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: docker, npm

Stumbled across this error as I try to run NPM on my docker container.

```
 FATAL  EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read                                                                                      19:05:13

  at Object.readSync (node:fs:723:3)
  at tryReadSync (node:fs:433:20)
  at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:479:19)
  at loadEnv (node_modules/@nuxt/config/dist/config.js:1152:78)
  at Object.loadNuxtConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/config/dist/config.js:1070:15)
  at loadNuxtConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:338:32)
  at NuxtCommand.getNuxtConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:463:26)
  at Object.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-start.js:115:30)
  at NuxtCommand.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:413:22)
```

> So in my case `npm install` worked just fine....when you try to run
> the app with `npm run start` your greeted with the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What it was not:

- File permission issue - was running command as root
- `.npmrc` in the same directory or user directory issue

### Solution

Add all your python virtual environment folders to `.dockerignore` in my case i wasn't even copying the virtual environment folder to my docker container. Its existence is what caused the issue.

**Example**

**.dockerignore**

```
/api/.env
```

Its weird and I don't know why this is happening...but i spent days trying to figure out why my build worked on deployment but wouldn't work locally - *python virtual environments are ignored during deployment so they were never there during cloud build thats why it worked.*

Here is more resource regarding the issue however these did not work for me:

- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4336
- [NPM stuck giving the same error EISDIR: Illegal operation on a directory, read at error (native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This was exactly my problem! Thank you very much!!!