# NPM stuck giving error EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, lstat

Tags: laravel, npm-install, inertiajs

I'm developing a Laravel / Inertia application.
So I was installing Laravel Breeze Starterkit following the procedure at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-inertia in a Docker local installation (Docker Desktop)

I installer Vue frontend with sail artisan breeze:install vue

Now when I go for "npm install"

```
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path \\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\magostoni\mycode\lv-vue-laracast\node_modules\.bin\acorn
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, lstat '\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\magostoni\mycode\lv-vue-laracast\node
_modules\.bin\acorn'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Matteo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-20T13_19_40_452Z-debug-0.log
```

NPM 8.19.2

Do you have any idea?

Kind regards,
Matteo

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42677294/11021885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and ran npm commands on the wsl machine directly without prepending "sail" to npm install.

Steps to success:

Bring up the docker container using sail in detached mode (`-d)`:

`./vendor/bin/sail up -d`

This way you can still execute commands.

So this throws the error you described:

`npm install`

This will run successfully:

`sail npm install`

Hope, that helps...