# npm command does nothing - windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

there are a lot of people here asking the same question and I tried almost all the answers but nothing worked for me ..

The problem is , **I can't run any npm command**, I installed node js from the windows installer [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) , and when I write any npm command for example: "npm install" or "npm start" nothing happens, I tried reinstalling and removing paths from environment variables but no luck..

I also tried Upgrading npm on Windows from this [link](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade) , when I write this command

```
npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
```

nothing happens , just like any other npm commands.. I tried also fixing this issue by what was written in the same page [here](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade#fix-an-attempted-upgrade)  but no luck also :(

What seems to be the problem guys ? thank you so much

*Those are the paths that I have in environment variables now:*

```
user variables path: C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm
system variables path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Comment: What does 'nothing happens' mean? No error message at all? Has the folder that npm has been installed to not been added to the path?

Comment: no error message , no lines , nothing at all :) .. the path has been added to the path

Comment: Does `npm -v` work?

Comment: No `npm -v` doesn't work, but `node -v` works fine , it gives me this `v4.4.7
`

Comment: OK, all I can see by way of suggestions is uninstalling node, deleting the contents of all the user folders etc. and re-installing. Sorry! :(

Comment: I added the paths that I have in environment variables in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that there was an old version of Node.js installed on this PC before.

**So to solve this problem** I had t reinstall and uninstall several versions of Node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) until one of then worked..

*[This helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32704849/5342709)*