# npm not responding after changing the prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, ionic-framework, npm

I tried updating my IONIC CLI through the npm recently, the installation were successful a couple of time but the CLI version did not change. After a research I decided to change the npm prefix, then the IONIC strated throwing up bash: IONIC command not found. Then I did a further research after which I edited the npm config through windows cmd admin. I did

```
 npm  cofig edit
```

I changed the prefix to

```
 \users\<username>\
```

since then, npm no longer respond.

if I run something like

```
npm install -g ionic
```

nothing happens, no errors nor any form of response.
 I have uninstall and reinstall the node several time. I am using node V4.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way around this . These are what I did

1. I deleted all the node_module folders in all my application (I am not sure if this is really necessary )
2. I did a complete uninstall of the node by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/1363169
3. I ran

   ```
   npm root -g
   ```

   which returns the path

   ```
   C:\Users\<username>\node_module
   ```

   instead of

   ```
    /usr/local
   ```

   or wherever node is installed , in my own case node is install in

   ```
    C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
   ```

   I then ran

   ```
     npm config set prefix "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm"
   ```

Then I reinstalled cordova and ionic again

```
    npm install  -g cordova
      npm install ionic -g
```

and all is well again