# npm not responding after modifying the prefix

Tags: node.js, npm

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178366/how-to-change-the-npm-prefix-without-config).
The npm command show no response at all.

I find `npm.cmd`, and comment the `@ECHO OFF` and run `npm -v`, I get:

```
C:\Users\Office>npm -v

C:\Users\Office>SETLOCAL

C:\Users\Office>SET "NODE_EXE=D:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe"

C:\Users\Office>IF NOT EXIST "D:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" (SET "NODE_EXE=node" )

C:\Users\Office>SET "NPM_CLI_JS=D:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"

C:\Users\Office>FOR /F "delims=" %F IN ('CALL "D:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\Program Files\
nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g') DO (SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%F\node_modules\
npm\bin\npm-cli.js" )
```

then nothing happen.
the file at `~\.npmrc` shows `prefix="'C:\\Users\\Office\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm'"`.
However, the folder C:\Users\Office\AppData\Roaming\npm is empty!!

I've reinstalled the nodejs many times. and follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250705/npm-not-responding-after-changing-the-prefix) won't help. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem by changing `prefix="'C:\\Users\\Office\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm'"` to `prefix="C:\\Users\\Office\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"`

i.e. removing the signle quotation mark.