# Starting node server gives node fibers error

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I was working on node. Everything was fine. I reinstalled my windows and now when I start node server, it gives me the following error.

[image]

I reinstalled fibers as well but still the same issue. Any guesses what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats sounds to me for reinstalling node.js completely, see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/7564182).
The hard thing is to install the globale modules (those which you have installed with npm -g before you've started the project). From your project make a copy without the node_modules and enter npm install. This worked for me, but I have to deal with the error messages which are missing the global modules.