# Installing node.js v6.11.2 does not install proper npm version on windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, failed-installation

I'm finding that when I attempt to install node.js v6.11.2 on my Windows 7 machine, it is installing the wrong version of npm along with it.  I've downloaded the installer directly from node.js' website where it states that 6.11.2 includes npm 3.10.10.  However, when I check my npm version using

```
npm -v
```

it says I have version 2.12.0 and throws the following at me:

> (node:4916) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported.  If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.

Comment: when you type node -v the real version printed is 6.11.2 ??

Comment: Do you have an old version installed? You can update to v4 with `npm install -g npm@^4`. (v5 is buggy).

Comment: node -v says v6.11.2.  I'll try and update to v4 and see what happens.

Comment: Attempting to update to v4 of npm throws an error.  "process.getuid is not a function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after completely removing node.js from my computer and re-installing node.js, I now have the proper expected version of npm.  I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) on how to completely remove it from my computer.  I had to go and manually delete the folders in user/appdata/roaming.  I guess they weren't included as part of the uninstall process.