# Cant' uninstall node.js properly

Tags: node.js

I uninstalled node.js like I would normally uninstall any other program, but when I go to command prompt and write `node -v` , I get 
`v0.12.2`. I have no idea why.

*P.S  I'm using Windows 10.*

Comment: type `which node` maybe you have multiple instances installed

Comment: @Mozly can you explain it better please? I'm not sure how to write this command.

Comment: type exactly: `which node` into your terminal and you should see the path to the program

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x

Comment: which platform you are working on?

Comment: @SatishPatel I'm working on Windows 10

Comment: @Mozly I'm working on Windows , not Mac OS

Comment: please tell what you have tried for uninstall. edit the question and what you have tried can can you tell.

Answer (score 0):

Open the start menu, type `add or remove programs` , select 'add or remove programs`, look for nodejs and click uninstall.

source:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

Comment: That's exactly what I did

Comment: Have you also made sure that all the nodejs processes were closed when you uninstalled? You can close the processes by using Task Manager.

Comment: Do you still see Nodejs in your `program and and Features` menu?

Comment: No, after uninstalling it's not in the `program and features ` menu anymore

Comment: Did you try what was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/881032)?

Comment: According to @lumio's article, one thing you can try is to reinstall nodejs over your current version. Then close all the running processes and try to uninstall again.

Comment: @lumio I tried it and it worked, thanks