# Cannot find module 'har-schema'

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I am trying to make ionic2 app. But npm is not supporting. It always gives me this error.[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "But npm is not supporting"?

Comment: @ram npm gives error "Cannot find module 'har-schema' ".
you can check above image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install previous version of npm:

```
npm install npm@5.2 -g
```

Unfortunatelly, current version(5.3) has a lot of bugs.

Comment: I have tried your solution. But same issue is still there.

Comment: Have you checked after, you have `npm -v` === `5.2` ?

Comment: I have npm -v === 4.1.2

Comment: Looks like not 5.2

Comment: @WebTesting what do you mean, that you have the same issue? You still try to install version 5.3?

Comment: no, I am not tryin to install npm 5.3
I am facing same issue "Cannot find module 'har-schema' ".
whenever I try to update version of npm. Right now I am unable to update version of npm.

Comment: I have tried to uninstalling and re-installing node and npm. But it didn't worked. Still i was facing Cannot find module 'har-schema' error.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of it. Solution is uninstall node and npm completely from your PC and then re-install it.
to uninstall node and npm completely check this link.
[How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
npm install -g --only=production --save har-schema
```