# How can I remove the npm registry from my machine?

Tags: npm, registry, uninstallation

I published a module to npm. When I uninstall it and try to reinstall it, this is always done from a cache ( it is done even if I'm not connected to the internet, I just get a warning ). I would like to try if my module installs correctly from the remote npm repository on a fresh npm registry.

I tried to remove Node.js and reinstall it, but it does not help. There is no "npm" in the list of my applications that I could remove, only Node.js is listed. This is on a Windows 10 machine.

Where is the npm registry located and how can I remove it entirely?

Comment: You could try running [npm cache clean](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/try-clearing-the-npm-cache) to clear the npm cache. Further details [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache#details).

Comment: Been there, done that, does not help. Also I tried this answer giving locations of npm files to delete, to no avail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows. Somehow this zombie installation can still make a link between the local directory and the module name. Also after removing everything, npm publish does not ask for credentials, so they must be stored somewhere ( notwithstanding that I deleted .npmrc from my user directory ). It seems once you installed npm, you cannot get rid of it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean your NPM cache and then clear your registry using the below commands.

```
npm cache clean
npm config delete registry
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```js
npm config delete registry
```

This worked for me