# Many unnecessary files generated by 'npm install' in root directory of app

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Usually when I do 'npm install' inside my application directory, bunch of npm libraries files gets generated inside node_modules folder which is expected.
Today suddenly I started seeing many files getting generated inside application directory and outside node_modules.

Did anyone face this issue ? and if yes - any workaround ? Screenshot attached. Lot's of .cmd file, don't know why they are here.

[image: My application folder structures]

Comment: Why do you think these files are unnecessary ? Sounds like batch versions of the bash scripts.

Comment: Coz when I did 'npm install' in ubuntu, it didn't generate all such files outside node_modules. It started creating now in windows npm.

Comment: Maybe it's plateform specific. What does the npm _install_ script look like ?

Comment: Yeah, may be on windows only those .cmd files get generated. By theway,  npm install calls "node-gyp rebuild" and node-gyp is script present at https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/bin/node-gyp.js

Comment: I don't think _node-gyp_ creates files on its own. Anyway I guess you can always manually remove the files you don't need in your project.

Comment: So these files should normally be created in the node_modules folder, beside the package.json file.

As @sean-chase alluded to, the "prefix" property can cause this behaviour. It might be defined in a .npmrc file (which might be defined in several places) or it might even be supplied to the npm install command:

    npm install --prefix=. foo

Answer (score 2):

Edit your c:\Users{username}.npmrc and remove the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and was able to resolve this by completely uninstalling + re-installing Node/npm:

[How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)