# I get an error when intalling Angular CLI with npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I tried reinstalling node.js a few times, and tried with different versions, and I still get the same error. I'm also running the CMD as administrator. It seems like it doesn't find json-schema, I even tried to install it manually, but same error appears. Here's the error message I get:

```
C:\> npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-edb66af1\node_modules\asn1' -> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\asn1-98b68b78'

npm ERR! path C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\json-schema' -> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\.json-schema.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-15T07_42_19_026Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: may be check and update your npm

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is like you, first of all, try to uninstall node and angular from your machine and remove the related files then again install it one by one accordingly it will work as I faced the same issue before. I am attaching some links which help me for removing angular and node.

[How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

For removing completely angular

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache verify

Comment: It's not working either. I removed everything but it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

What version of npm are you running ('`npm -v`')?

I'd suggest that you run at least npm version 5.3.0 - the current version is 5.7.1, but I've run into issues (as have others) with permissions behavior on Windows with some of the later versions.

If you need to install a different version of npm, type the command `npm install -g npm@5.3.0` (or whichever version you want to install).