# firebase deploy fails with lots of errors

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

After updating firebase-tools from the suggestion that display when doing a firebase deploy, i can no longer user firebase-tools. I get all kinds of errors and nothing works any longer. I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs/npm with [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

After reinstalling nodejs and trying to reinstall firebase-tools i still get tons of errors and can no longer deploy anything. Its completely broken! Help

Errors from firebase deploy
[image]

Errors from npm install inside the firebase function directory
[image]

Comment: Find and delete the cordova folder then reinstall cordova

Comment: ` c:\> npm install -g cordova` on PC