# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at createScript (vm.js:80:10)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've just arted to learn node, and when executing a very simple app from a powershell terminal:

```
node app.js
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
PS C:\Users\kisco\Source\Repos\library> node app.js
C:\Users\kisco\Source\Repos\library\app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��v
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
PS C:\Users\kisco\Source\Repos\library>
```

Here's my source for `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello from my libvrary app')
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Looks like you might have accidentally added a BOM to the start of the `app.js` file.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts how would i remove it ?

Comment: Copy from the `a` in the first `var` statement, make a new file, re-add the `v` and overwrite the `app.js` with the fresh file I guess?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no luck. i did exactly what you said, copied from the ```a``` until the last character and pasted it into a new file

Comment: how  did you create this `app.js` file ? @l--''''''---------''''''''''''

Comment: You might need to check what encoding your text editor is saving with, or consider using a different one altogether.

Comment: i've switched to a bash terminal and getting the same result: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1ccXsy2OBaTVff0jNfoS7GYew5-d0M2Pp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like there is some `encoding` issue with the file that you're trying to run with `Node`. Sometimes, files created with some command line utility does some encoding issues with the file. So, I would suggest not to use them to create file. Just create file with `Right-Click > New File > app.js` and replace your old file with this `app.js`. And try running `node app.js`.

Answer (score 4):

It may happen due to mismatch of node versions. Please check the compatible version for your code repo.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my case, I had two node version installed, for diff projects. And it was picking an older one on ng serve. Just remove one version or point to particular node version before hit start command.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by updating my version of node on Ubuntu 16

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by deleting the entire node module and reinstalling.

Comment: it works, thanks!  how to delete all node js, npm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My problem was that I copy-pasted code from a website and the '"' were wrongly formatted by my editor. So, I replaced all those quotations with " or ', whichever is applicable.

That solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced smilier issue.

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
```

But in my case, i was using nvm and forgot to switch the node version to latest version. After switching to latest version it works and did not get this exception

Answer (score 1):

For me I was using the wrong version of node/npm on which the node modules where installed.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when trying to run a program I compiled as an executable. Instead of just running `./program` I was trying to run it with node. So I did `node ./program`.

Trying to run the executable (compiled with pkg for linux) with node gave me pretty much the exact same error you got here.

Comment: Whether you were able to find solution for this? I have created sample application and tried to package with  

pkg . --debug

packaging was successful , but when I tried to run with

node testapp it gave me following error

(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ����
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js....

Comment: Because it's compiled as an executable, you need to run it as one. So instead of `node testapp` you need to run `./testapp`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. And indeed it was an encoding problem. 
Our js file was parsing another file which had been copied/pasted from a pdf.
Turned out there was a corrupted space character in the middle of the file.

Removing it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all I had to do was unistall webstorm (in your case it might be whatever text editor it is you are using for your Repository to work on your project), delete my project folder and install webstorm afresh then running the following after getting my Repository from github

```
npm init 
npm install mysql
npm install colors
```

and then node `index.js` and I got my server running up again.

Note that I had to update my NodeJS to the latest version.