# Truffle: "Invalid or unexpected token" when running promise function

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

When I run any function in the truffle console, it returns "Invalid or unexpected token."

This is the full error return:

```
truffle(development)> app.candidates(1).then(function(c) {candidate = c;})
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:280:10)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:468:10)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
at bound (domain.js:301:14)
at ReplManager.interpret (C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\repl.js:119:1)
at Console.interpret (C:\Users\Jakob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\console.js:164:1)
at Object.runInContext (vm.js:119:10)
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
```

I just started my first dApp project following a tutorial on YouTube and am fairly new to this. If any more information is required, ask and I will help you out.

So far I tried the same setup on my Mac OSX and it worked perfectly fine. Could it be a step I'm missing on windows or a missing dependency?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: what is your nodejs version?

Comment: @WilliamChong v8.11.3

Comment: Th error does not print out the unexpected token, and since it works on OSX, would it be a windows specific encoding problem? something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203953/syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-at-createscript-vm-js8010

Comment: Would using Bash on Windows 10 an option for you? It dodges a lot of windows specific problem when running node.js

Comment: I mean the new Ubuntu based bash on win10 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: @WilliamChong It worked! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not really answering why your syntax error occurs, it seems to be a Windows specific problem on node.js, probably related to encoding.

These kind of problem can be easily avoided using Bash on Windows 10.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10