# Electron - App threw an error during load

Tags: electron

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d40Px.png)

All on a sudden electron started showing this error. Electron Version 3.0.0 
Where should I try debugging?

EDIT: Found the error and its solution here: [SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at createScript (vm.js:80:10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203953/syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-at-createscript-vm-js8010)

It was not syntax error.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Could you provide the code also?

Comment: Got the answer here. It was not a syntax error. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203953/syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-at-createscript-vm-js8010