# IntelliJ: why does Node.js launcher crash in debug mode?

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm

I wrote a very simple Typescript file and called it "app2.ts".

I created the following launcher in IntelliJ:

[image]

When I run this launcher, everything works properly. However, when I run it in debug mode, I get the following error in console:

(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>       at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
>       at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:824:12)

Do you know what is the problem and why the configuration works in run mode, and doesn't work in debug mode?

Comment: Good to refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203953/syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-at-createscript-vm-js8010

Comment: @MebinJoe, I read it. If it were an encoding issue, the program wouldn't pass in run mode.

Comment: Please create a support ticket and attach a project that can be used to recreate the issue