# "npm run build" fails with SyntaxError:Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to deploy my app to AWS and encountered an error when executing "npm run build".
This error seems to be relevant with webpack.config.js, but I have no idea since I haven't modified anything to that file.

I found a similar question here but it did not help that much.
[SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at createScript (vm.js:80:10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203953/syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-at-createscript-vm-js8010/56901041)

```
<error log>
/var/www/gamestocker/app/GameStocker/react_view/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js:306
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/gamestocker/app/GameStocker/react_view/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:38:23)

npm ERR! Linux 4.14.173-137.229.amzn2.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! gamestocker@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gamestocker@0.1.0 build script 'react-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the gamestocker package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs gamestocker
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls gamestocker
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/gamestocker/app/GameStocker/react_view/npm-debug.log
```

Below is the part of webpack.config.js that the error log mentions.
or may be in vm.js file

```
<webpack.config.js>
.
.
.
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
.
.
.
```

I would appreciate it if you could provide any suggestion or possible reasons.
Thanks :)

[EDITED

```
<vm.js>
var test = require('tape');
var vm = require('../');

test('vmRunInNewContext', function (t) {
    t.plan(6);

    t.equal(vm.runInNewContext('a + 5', { a : 100 }), 105);

    (function () {
        var vars = { x : 10 };
        t.equal(vm.runInNewContext('x++', vars), 10);
        t.equal(vars.x, 11);
    })();

    (function () {
        var vars = { x : 10 };
        t.equal(vm.runInNewContext('var y = 3; y + x++', vars), 13);
        t.equal(vars.x, 11);
        t.equal(vars.y, 3);
    })();

    t.end();
});

test('vmRunInContext', function (t) {
    t.plan(2);

    var context = vm.createContext({ foo: 1 });

    vm.runInContext('var x = 1', context);
    t.deepEqual(context, { foo: 1, x: 1 });

    vm.runInContext('var y = 1', context);
    t.deepEqual(context, { foo: 1, x: 1, y: 1 });
});
```

Comment: please share vm.jd file

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion arisan. I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the code is being run with a slightly older JavaScript engine, from before spread properties were added in ES2018. (Spread for *iterables* was added in ES2015, but property spread was only added in ES2018.)

If you can't upgrade the environment to something more recent, you can switch to `Object.assign`:

```
alias: Object.assign(
    {
      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web'
    },
    // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
    isEnvProductionProfile && {
      'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
      'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
    },
    modules.webpackAliases || {}
),
```

`Object.assign` was added in ES2015.

---

Side note: You can replace

```
    modules.webpackAliases || {}
```

with just

```
    modules.webpackAliases || {}
```

above. `Object.assign` (and property spread) effectively ignore it if you pass them a falsy value instead of an object. (It's not literally true, they only explicitly ignore `null` and `undefined`; all others are converted to the equivalent object and then their enumerable own properties are used — but the objects that `false`, `0`, `NaN`, and `""` are converted to don't have any enumerable own properties. Just don't pass `document.all` to it, which is falsy but does have enumerable own properties... [Yes, `document.all` is really falsy. I cover that bizarre historical artefact in Chapter 17 of my book *JavaScript: The New Toys*.])

Comment: Thanks for the comment Crowder. I see. The error log indeed mentions the spread operator. How can I handle it in this case?

Comment: @ryo.m.code - It depends on what version of JavaScript the runtime you're using supports. Ideally, upgrade it to a more recent version that supports property spread. But if you can't do that, it may have `Object.assign`, which was added in ES2015. I've show how to use it for `alias` above.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instruction. I replaced it with your code, then I got another syntax error. /var/www/gamestocker/app/GameStocker/react_view/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js:313
      ),
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)

Comment: @ryo.m.code - Doh! If the JavaScript engine is that old, it won't like that trailing comma on the function call, just before the closing `)`. Remove the `,` at the end of the second-to-last line after `modules.webpackAliases || {}` (I've removed it above). (Side note: You can safely remove the `|| {}`, `Object.assign` [and property spread] effectively ignore all falsy values.)

Comment: You are right. I changed it again and another SyntaxError for a different part appeared. /var/www/gamestocker/app/GameStocker/react_view/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:375
    const optimizeFn = async (compilation, chunks) => {
async function is not available either for the old version right? I might have to update the engine itself. Do I have to work with EC2 itself in this case to upgrade the engine?

Comment: @ryo.m.code - Yeah, `async` functions were also added in ES2018. You'll be best off upgrading the engine. Unfortunately, I don't know how you do that. :-|

Comment: Thanks for a set of advice Crowder! It still helped me a lot! I will keep investigating on this. Thanks again :)