# ...(isenvproductionprofile && ^^^ syntaxerror unexpected token in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

i have problem with command npm run build, when i use her i get message:

```
/var/www/vhosts/medboard.pl/httpdocs/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.c                                                                                                             onfig.js:306
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/medboard.pl/httpdocs/node_modules/rea                                                                                                             ct-app-rewired/scripts/build.js:22:23)
```

when i do like in this post:
["npm run build" fails with SyntaxError:Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61834173/npm-run-build-fails-with-syntaxerrorunexpected-token)

im getting error:

```
/var/www/vhosts/medboard.pl/httpdocs/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/ter                                                                                                             ser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:375
    const optimizeFn = async (compilation, chunks) => {
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/medboard.pl/httpdocs/node_modules/rea                                                                                                             ct-scripts/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js:3:16)
```

Comment: What version of node are you using? Native [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#browser_compatibility) is version 7.6.0 and [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#browser_compatibility) is version 8.3.0. Try running `node --version` to see what you have.

Comment: `[root@server-1499595-1 httpdocs]# /opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node --version
v12.4.0` but when i check version in httpdoc i have `[root@server-1499595-1 httpdocs]# node --version
v6.17.1`, best thing is yesterday everthing was ok, today when i try build i got this error