# Your application was recycled due to an intermittent Azure infrastructure issue while accessing remote file storage

Tags: reactjs, azure, syncfusion, gantt-chart

I've been testing the syncfusion's ej2-react-gantt component locally for a while and then i had to push it into a remote server to be tested and validated by my superior (our app is hosted and running in MS azure) but since then the app didn't work anymore online and we're getting this message :

> :( Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can
> access the diagnostic resources.

Internally in the server, we got also this message

> Your application was recycled due to an intermittent Azure
> infrastructure issue while accessing remote file storage.

Anybody has a clue about this problem ?

************* **EDIT** ****************

I reverted the project to an older version (for which there isn't a problem with azure) and then i had to update the following syncfusion modules versions to the latest's and then i had the problem again with azure !

Now after i saw azure this following log in the moment when the problem happened the first time  and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203953/syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-at-createscript-vm-js8010/50204147), i think there is an encoding problem in one or more of these module's files

[image]

```
Container statshfront2_0_f23a1979 couldn't be started: Logs = 2020-06-25T16:40:30.355869187Z   _____                               
2020-06-25T16:40:30.355896187Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2020-06-25T16:40:30.355911087Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2020-06-25T16:40:30.355915587Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2020-06-25T16:40:30.355919787Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2020-06-25T16:40:30.355923987Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2020-06-25T16:40:30.355927787Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2020-06-25T16:40:30.355931587Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:30.355934987Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2020-06-25T16:40:30.355938587Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2020-06-25T16:40:30.356232890Z NodeJS Version : v8.1.4
2020-06-25T16:40:30.356244991Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2020-06-25T16:40:30.356249691Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:31.610948591Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2020-06-25T16:40:31.619660224Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2020-06-25T16:40:31.619676823Z Build Operation ID: e91e643c-631a-400e-a19f-44d98d148779
2020-06-25T16:40:34.592032734Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2020-06-25T16:40:35.254945792Z Running #!/bin/sh
2020-06-25T16:40:35.255598896Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:35.255611296Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2020-06-25T16:40:35.255616496Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2020-06-25T16:40:35.255620796Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:35.256568503Z export NODE_PATH=$(npm root --quiet -g):$NODE_PATH
2020-06-25T16:40:35.256580503Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2020-06-25T16:40:35.256585503Z      export PORT=8080
2020-06-25T16:40:35.256590003Z fi
2020-06-25T16:40:35.257544409Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:35.257555009Z pm2 start --no-daemon server.js
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448432822Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448474522Z                         -------------
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448481322Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448485422Z __/\\\\\\\\\\\\\____/\\\\____________/\\\\____/\\\\\\\\\_____
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448490522Z  _\/\\\/////////\\\_\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\__/\\\///////\\\___
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448495622Z   _\/\\\_______\/\\\_\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\///______\//\\\__
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448500422Z    _\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\/__\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\___________/\\\/___
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448505422Z     _\/\\\/////////____\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\________/\\\//_____
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448510322Z      _\/\\\_____________\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_____/\\\//________
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448521522Z       _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\___/\\\/___________
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448526322Z        _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448531022Z         _\///______________\///______________\///__\///////////////__
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448535522Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448539322Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448543322Z                           Runtime Edition
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448547422Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448551222Z         PM2 is a Production Process Manager for Node.js applications
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448555423Z                      with a built-in Load Balancer.
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448559423Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448563323Z                 Start and Daemonize any application:
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448567323Z                 $ pm2 start app.js
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448571323Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448575123Z                 Load Balance 4 instances of api.js:
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448579223Z                 $ pm2 start api.js -i 4
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448583223Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448587023Z                 Monitor in production:
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448591023Z                 $ pm2 monitor
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448595023Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448598823Z                 Make pm2 auto-boot at server restart:
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448602823Z                 $ pm2 startup
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448606823Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448610723Z                 To go further checkout:
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448614723Z                 http://pm2.io/
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448620023Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448623923Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448627723Z                         -------------
2020-06-25T16:40:42.448631723Z 
2020-06-25T16:40:42.467613770Z pm2 launched in no-daemon mode (you can add DEBUG="*" env variable to get more messages)
2020-06-25T16:40:43.828149584Z 2020-06-25T16:40:43: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2020-06-25T16:40:44.282080091Z 2020-06-25T16:40:44: PM2 log: [PM2] Starting /home/site/wwwroot/server.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
2020-06-25T16:40:44.292552872Z 2020-06-25T16:40:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2020-06-25T16:40:44.344485874Z 2020-06-25T16:40:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2020-06-25T16:40:44.361348604Z 2020-06-25T16:40:44: PM2 log: [PM2] Done.
2020-06-25T16:40:44.781288049Z 2020-06-25T16:40:44: PM2 log: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬──────┬──────────┐
2020-06-25T16:40:44.781335850Z │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user │ watching │
2020-06-25T16:40:44.781343250Z ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼──────┼──────────┤
2020-06-25T16:40:44.781358750Z │ server   │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 65  │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 15.2 MB   │ root │ disabled │
2020-06-25T16:40:44.781362650Z └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴──────┴──────────┘
2020-06-25T16:40:44.782246257Z 2020-06-25T16:40:44: PM2 log:  Use `pm2 show ` to get more details about an app
2020-06-25T16:40:44.782711560Z 2020-06-25T16:40:44: PM2 log: [--no-daemon] Continue to stream logs
2020-06-25T16:40:44.783193664Z 2020-06-25T16:40:44: PM2 log: [--no-daemon] Exit on target PM2 exit pid=50
2020-06-25T16:40:46.742255209Z 16:40:46 0|server  | /home/site/wwwroot/server.js:55549
2020-06-25T16:40:46.742855913Z 16:40:46 0|server  |   ...POSIX_CHARS,
2020-06-25T16:40:46.744021021Z 16:40:46 0|server  |   ^^^
2020-06-25T16:40:46.750738966Z 16:40:46 0|server  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
2020-06-25T16:40:46.751418271Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:46.752013875Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:46.753315883Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
2020-06-25T16:40:46.761168636Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:46.761941541Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
2020-06-25T16:40:46.762895048Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
2020-06-25T16:40:46.764105856Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
2020-06-25T16:40:46.770489698Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
2020-06-25T16:40:46.771113603Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
2020-06-25T16:40:46.772218610Z 16:40:46 0|server  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:47.376735861Z 2020-06-25T16:40:47: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2020-06-25T16:40:47.387844136Z 16:40:47 PM2       | App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2020-06-25T16:40:47.395104584Z 2020-06-25T16:40:47: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2020-06-25T16:40:47.396347393Z 16:40:47 PM2       | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2020-06-25T16:40:47.424028678Z 2020-06-25T16:40:47: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2020-06-25T16:40:47.433657243Z 16:40:47 PM2       | App [server:0] online
2020-06-25T16:40:49.169624995Z 16:40:49 0|server  | /home/site/wwwroot/server.js:55549
2020-06-25T16:40:49.170659102Z 16:40:49 0|server  |   ...POSIX_CHARS,
2020-06-25T16:40:49.171469707Z 16:40:49 0|server  |   ^^^
2020-06-25T16:40:49.172399414Z 16:40:49 0|server  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
2020-06-25T16:40:49.180743270Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.181440474Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.200840904Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.202163713Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.231021907Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.238462557Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.239754766Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.268565959Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.268596559Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.268625159Z 16:40:49 0|server  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:49.819286456Z 2020-06-25T16:40:49: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2020-06-25T16:40:49.827835813Z 16:40:49 PM2       | App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2020-06-25T16:40:49.828812219Z 2020-06-25T16:40:49: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2020-06-25T16:40:49.836737373Z 16:40:49 PM2       | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2020-06-25T16:40:49.856404005Z 2020-06-25T16:40:49: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2020-06-25T16:40:49.857379511Z 16:40:49 PM2       | App [server:0] online
2020-06-25T16:40:51.492609087Z 16:40:51 0|server  | /home/site/wwwroot/server.js:55549
2020-06-25T16:40:51.493979896Z 16:40:51 0|server  |   ...POSIX_CHARS,
2020-06-25T16:40:51.494613100Z 16:40:51 0|server  |   ^^^
2020-06-25T16:40:51.512608721Z 16:40:51 0|server  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
2020-06-25T16:40:51.513377526Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:51.513934030Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:51.543018225Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
2020-06-25T16:40:51.561917852Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:51.561966952Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
2020-06-25T16:40:51.571907719Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
2020-06-25T16:40:51.573337429Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
2020-06-25T16:40:51.573960033Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
2020-06-25T16:40:51.580278475Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
2020-06-25T16:40:51.580703878Z 16:40:51 0|server  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
2020-06-25T16:40:52.100250465Z 2020-06-25T16:40:52: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2020-06-25T16:40:52.102235979Z 16:40:52 PM2       | App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2020-06-25T16:40:52.108695122Z 2020-06-25T16:40:52: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2020-06-25T16:40:52.109783629Z 16:40:52 PM2       | App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2020-06-25T16:40:52.139853731Z 2020-06-25T16:40:52: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2020-06-25T16:40:52.156522043Z 16:40:52 PM2       | App [server:0] online
2020-06-25T16:40:53.683821494Z 16:40:53 0|server  | /home/site/wwwroot/server.js:55549
```

************* **EDIT2** ****************

i have a collegue who cloned our app project on his pc and his git tool says that some files have bad signature and he found binary files

[image]

i guess the problem is similar to the one in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855712/why-does-git-treat-this-text-file-as-a-binary-file/6856566)

Comment: I suggest you ask this question at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was finally fixed , it turned out to be caused by an old node version on azure which doesn't compile ES6..