# Cannot Install Any Package NPM Node-JS

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

The problem I face is when I will install one of the packages NPM is always show

`[............] /roolbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session ....`

and the final show error like :

```
npm ERR! code e503 
npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable:

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:Users\.......\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-08t08_09_25_773Z-debug.log
```

I have already found a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows). But it didn't worked.

The configuration NodeJS in my system :
[image]

and i use version for

- **NodeJS**  : 10.8.0
- **npm**     : 6.2.3

Please help me for fixed my problem...

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it will fix your issue but i used 
`npm install --proxy proxy_address:port install package_name --save`
when i had troubles with proxy, if this works, then you might have configured npm settings not the way you need to.

Comment: There may be several reasons for it, since I don't know much about your connection, I would suggest using something like proxifier app, so you can force your system to use global proxy while downloading packages. If even this does not work, then probably problem is in your connection

Comment: I think it's the problem in my proxy network, i try to get address https://registry.npmjs.org in my browser when using proxy, the result is address cannot be reached. But, when i not use the proxy, the address is working and show json data. But i don't know to handle my proxy to fixed this problem...