# node server.js will work but npm start won't

Tags: node.js, npm

I am having trouble running a node app with npm. When I try `node server.js` it will work, but when I try `npm start` it gives me the following error:

```
npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! path bash
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! sample-app@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sample-app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-01T11_57_12_947Z-debug.log
```

My package.json includes start script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

And this is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

I recently updated to 10.13.0 version of Node if that might be the issue? I have tried cleaning the cache already.

This is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Nick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle sample-app@1.0.0~prestart: sample-app@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle sample-app@1.0.0~start: sample-app@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle sample-app@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle sample-app@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\repos\sample-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.4.3\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.4.3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Nick\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\adb;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.4.3\mingw\bin;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\local\bin;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\hyper\app-2.0.0\resources\bin;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle sample-app@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\repos\sample-app
10 silly lifecycle sample-app@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node server.js' ]
11 info lifecycle sample-app@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
12 silly lifecycle sample-app@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: -4058  signal: null
13 info lifecycle sample-app@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: sample-app@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
14 verbose stack spawn bash ENOENT
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
14 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
14 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
15 verbose pkgid sample-app@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\repos\sample-app
17 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
18 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Nick\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 verbose node v10.13.0
20 verbose npm  v6.4.1
21 error file bash
22 error path bash
23 error code ELIFECYCLE
24 error errno ENOENT
25 error syscall spawn bash
26 error sample-app@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
26 error spawn bash ENOENT
27 error Failed at the sample-app@1.0.0 start script.
27 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My directory looks like this:

```
sample-app
|--- node_modules
|--- package.json
|--- package-lock.json
|--- server.js
```

Comment: did you try node.js command promt and got error?

Comment: I tried in command prompt and in powershell, running with admin rights and so on. Nothing works

Comment: is there no useful information in the complete log ? ENOENT means Error No Entry so a directory or file is missing somewhere ...

Comment: I have edited the post to include the log.

Comment: You should show us your folder directory. The obvious problem is that server.js may not be in the root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it. Had to uninstall node completely using the answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/4913357) and then install node and npm from scratch. I guess it was some conflict with the PATH variable. Everything works fine now. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem. If you are on Windows, make sure that `%userprofile%\.npmrc` contains `script-shell=cmd`. Spent hours trying to figure this bug out...