# Installing Node JS on Windows 7 stuck on a command prompt

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm trying to install Node JS v8.12.0 on Windows 7, using the following installer downloaded from the Node website: https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-win-x86.zip

When I run the installer, it just hangs on the first window it opens - please see screen below.

It may have something to do with the fact that I uninstalled a previous version of Node by following this solution: [How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

I also had [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) installed previously, which I also uninstalled.

So I am trying to install Node again from scratch, but this time it just hangs forever.

I'm running it with Elevated Privileges on a work machine, which has always worked when installed Node in the past, including this version (8.12.0).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the binary version of Node for Windows.

Try to download and use this installer:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/node-v8.15.0-x86.msi