# Error: "Module parse failed: Unexpected token" when building react-static app template

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-static

I got this error when creating a fresh app from react-static blank template, after clean up the windows environment and reinstall nodejs and react-static, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) procedure.

> ERROR in
>   /.../react-static-test/react-static-test/dist/react-static-templates.js
>   1:1051 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:1051) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

The procedure is good, help me in pass more than once, but for some reason seams to be some instability in the package tree for react-static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution, taken from react-static [support](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8656), for next folk don't have to dig into web for it:

1. rm -rf node_modules
2. rm -rf package-lock.json
3. npm install
4. npm install acorn@6.0.5 -D
5. npm run serve

According to react-static support post, it is a npm bug.