# Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH. Could you tell me what the problem is?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

```
I'm using npm install -g yo gulp to install yeoman and this is the error I'm getting  
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
C:\Usr\local\gulp -> C:\Usr\local\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
C:\Usr\local\yo -> C:\Usr\local\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js
C:\Usr\local\yo-complete -> C:\Usr\local\node_modules\yo\lib\completion\index.js

> yo@3.1.0 postinstall C:\Usr\local\node_modules\yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

√ No .bowerrc file in home directory
√ Global configuration file is valid
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
√ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
√ Node.js version
{ Error: Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH
    at notFoundError (C:\Usr\local\node_modules\yo\node_modules\cross-spawn-async\lib\enoent.js:8:11)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Usr\local\node_modules\yo\node_modules\cross-spawn-async\lib\enoent.js:43:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Usr\local\node_modules\yo\node_modules\cross-spawn-async\lib\enoent.js:30:19)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yo',
  cmd: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c "yo "--version""' }
× yo version
{ Error: Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH
    at notFoundError (C:\Usr\local\node_modules\yo\node_modules\cross-spawn-async\lib\enoent.js:8:11)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Usr\local\node_modules\yo\node_modules\cross-spawn-async\lib\enoent.js:43:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Usr\local\node_modules\yo\node_modules\cross-spawn-async\lib\enoent.js:30:19)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yo',
  cmd: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c "yo "--version""' }
√ npm version

Found potential issues on your machine :(
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\gulp\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ gulp@4.0.2
+ yo@3.1.0
updated 2 packages in 23.31s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Xander Cage said.

1. I have uninstalled node.js -> [procedure here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)
2. I have restarted my PC.
3. Then I installed again node.js

It work.

Comment: Thank you it helped :)

Answer (score 13):

Run the following command to see where npm puts global packages

`npm config get prefix`

You'll get output similar to this

`/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0_1`

Copy the output or path and then using any code editor open your .bashrc or .zshrc file depending on the terminal you use and paste like so

`export PATH="$PATH:"/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0_1/bin/""`

Then after saving run

`source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: i've resolved the above issue by deleting the node js npm files and then uninstalling and reinstalling nodejs. The problem must be due to incomplete or improper installation I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The above didn't work for me at all.

The following solved my problem:
clean installed nodejs and followed steps by dv-here in thread: https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/100
Note that my npm kept pointing to C:\usr...

I think I set the `npm config set prefix=` to something mistakenly due to which I was >getting the error. Here's how I fixed it:

Open CMD in "Administrator" mode.

```
npm cache clear --force

npm install

npm config set cache C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

npm config set prefix C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! "Administrator" mode not required in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and I really didn't want uninstall nodejs as I have  a lot of package installed.
Tried also with the second answer and did not worked.

Then I found this ticked, that is been closed:

https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1716

install with yarn command for me worked.

```
yarn global add yo
```

Seem then the installation went through with also binary installed.

Nevermind try to install it with npm getting same error, so looking for provide more infos

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue on MacOS, and saw that all of my global npm binaries were symlinked into the `/usr/local/bin` directory, except for `yo`.  I created a symlink using this command:

`ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.10.0/bin/yo /usr/local/bin/yo`

(Yours may vary)

And `yo` is now callable.