# How to install Yoeman on Ubuntu18.04

Tags: npm, yeoman, yo

I am installing Yeoman on my machine and ran this 
`npm install -g yo`
This is giving me permission error:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/yo
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/yo'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/yo'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/yo'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/yo'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/siddharth/.npm/_logs/2020-04-24T22_31_29_025Z-debug.log
```

But this got resolved by attaching `sudo`

Now I am getting this error:

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ Node.js version
✔ npm version
Error: Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yo',
  path: 'yo',
  spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
  cmd: 'yo --version'
}
✖ yo version
Error: Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yo',
  path: 'yo',
  spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
  cmd: 'yo --version'
}

Found potential issues on your machine :(
+ yo@3.1.1
updated 1 package in 29.492s
```

Running `yo --version` is giving `zsh: command not found: yo`
I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58277450/10309895 but this is also not working for me
:,(

Comment: It seems that yeoman was installed for the elevated user. Does `sudo yo --version` find the `yo` command?

Comment: no @tenkmilan getting `zsh: command not found: yo `