# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory in all files of .stagging folder

Tags: node.js

I am getting the `ENOENT` No error such as file or directory errors in all files in the .stagging folder

I followed the following procedure to remove `nodejs` from my computer:

[How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

I still get the same errors

I'm creating an `angular` blank project

`ng new blankProject`

`npm version 6.12.0`

`node version v12.13.0`

It happens in `ionic`project

[erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pRtL.png)

Comment: What is the command you are using when getting those errors, and have you try installing dependencies after creating the project using $npm install

Comment: Could you open the virus safe of your virus scanner? If there are files inside it ending with `.js`, you virus scanner is causing this issue.

Comment: Vincent Roma ng new blankProject or npm install either one.

Comment: Ferrybig - I don't have access to my antivirus, but all computers here using the same antivirus