# NPM consumes all available memory

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, npm

I am trying to set up a basic node project. I have a fresh install of node (I have tried both Node 12 LTS and Node 13 on separate fresh installs.) When I try and run NPM, I get a heap limit error.

```
E:\Development\MyProject> npm help install --verbose
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF784B5021F napi_wrap+124591
 2: 00007FF784AF0296 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+35542
 3: 00007FF784AF0F66 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+38822
 4: 00007FF785317E6E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7852FF5C1 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+785
 6: 00007FF7851C690C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
 7: 00007FF7851D1C00 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
 8: 00007FF7851CE72F v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3151
 9: 00007FF7851C3E83 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
10: 00007FF7851C6A5A v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1770
11: 00007FF7851BCDC3 v8::base::CPU::has_vfp3+467
12: 00007FF784A9F70C v8::internal::wasm::JSToWasmWrapperCompilationUnit::~JSToWasmWrapperCompilationUnit+101820
13: 00007FF784A9E6A1 v8::internal::wasm::JSToWasmWrapperCompilationUnit::~JSToWasmWrapperCompilationUnit+97617
14: 00007FF784B99C5B uv_async_send+331
15: 00007FF784B993FC uv_loop_init+1212
16: 00007FF784B995C4 uv_run+244
17: 00007FF784ABC0F3 v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayWriter::source_position_table_builder+29635
18: 00007FF784B18080 node::Start+288
19: 00007FF7849D66FC RC4_options+339452
20: 00007FF785817678 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+1290008
21: 00007FFD91A67BD4 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
22: 00007FFD9334CED1 RtlUserThreadStart+33
```

This error occurs regardless of what `npm` command I run. I have tried increasing the memory limit using the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable, but that just makes NPM take longer to consume all the memory before failing.

What am I missing to be able to run NPM?

**Current Environment**

- Windows 10 w/ Powershell
- Node v13.2.0

**Edit 2**

May be worth noting that I have previously had this project and Node running, but had to remove the hard drive Node was installed on due to a drive failure. This is my attempt to put a fresh installation of Node on my machine.

**Edit 1**

Here is my `package.json`, though the error occurs both inside and outside a project.

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wp": "webpack",
    "seed-db": "seed --db-name myProject --data ./seeds --drop-collection"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "mongo-seeding": "^2.2.0",
    "mongo-seeding-cli": "^2.2.0",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `package.json` and `npmrc` files?

Comment: I have added my `package.json`, though I do not think it should have anything to do with the issue since the error occurs both within and outside the project. I have no `npmrc`

Comment: I asked because sometimes there are pre/post install scripts that do ugly things. I guess not in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple re-installs, I finally found the issue, helped by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/5708126). Per the context of the question, I recently had a drive failure and installed a new hard drive. This new hard drive was given a different name (swtiched from `A:` to `E:`.) I found an old `.npmrc` that I had missed on previous passes that pointed NPM to a missing location on the `A:` drive. Once I removed that file, restarted for good measure, and reinstalled Node, I was able to use NPM commands again.

It seems weird to me that this issue caused NPM to silently fail and eat all the memory.

Comment: Super strange. Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that this behaviour is odd. Since it is happening for any `npm` command you run wherever you run it, it might be that your npm install is just broken. Try re-installing `npm` from scratch, after deleting the old version.

Also, try using [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/), an alternative package manager. It's not ideal, but it might get you further ahead in your project.

Comment: Would that be the same as reinstalling Node from scratch? This all started when I swapped out a HD (the previous drive had my development stuff on it.) I've had npm / node working previously... I have entirely reinstalled it twice now in this iteration and haven't had any luck. I suppose there is a chance there are some remnants of a previous install in a temp or `appdata` location. I may try to reinstall from scratch again