# How to get node to install in the absence of original drive

Tags: node.js, windows

I installed node a while back to launch a bot for discord, but I installed it to an external flash drive (which on this device was D:). Unfortunately, I lost the drive, along with my bot and node. When I try to install node to my C:\ drive now, it opens the installer and immediately says D:\ does not exist, not letting me try to use the change, repair, or uninstall functions.

I've tried using `where node` and `node --version` and their npm counterparts, and command prompt simply tells me it has no clue what I'm talking about or it can't find node. Using different node versions does the same thing.

Since getting the drive back is out of the question, what can I do to get node to install?

Comment: You can try manual cleanup it first - most likely install picks up some configuration files from c drive (or some settings from registry). Here are instructions for an cleanup : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows