# No valid versions available for undefined when running npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Running Windows 10 Enterprise.

I am trying to install angular cli to run the angular project. I entered below command.

--> `npm install -g @angular/cli`

I m getting below error.

> --> npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
>   --> npm ERR! No valid versions available for undefined

what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be you have to uninstall the node version and have to install it again

Comment: ok try to remove node js completely by following  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) then install the current LTS version. Then try again

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the `npm install -g @angular/cli` You need to have the node installed. Please find the below link to install the relevent node version for your PC. And try running the `npm install -g @angular/cli` command again.

[Download the Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Comment: i have installed the node js and after that i m trying to run the command but it is giving same error

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure old ***node_modules*** are completely deleted and ***package-lock.json*** . Try fresh ***npm install*** now

```
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```