# Unable to run vue command

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying run the `vue` command on the Windows command prompt.
I installed Node and then Vue CLI by using command `npm install -g @vue/cli`, but when I run `vue create test`, I see an error. I reinstalled Node and `@vue/cli`, but that didn't work. Here's the error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: if you type `vue-cli --version` in the termina, what is the output ?

Comment: I got "'vue-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." @V.Sambor

Comment: sorry, try `vue --version`

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Comment: I got same error as I posted image in the question. @V.Sambor

Comment: node version v6.10.3 @tony19

Comment: Please help me. I'm trying to solve it since few days .@tony19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue CLI requires Node 8.9+, as stated in the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html):

> #### Node Version Requirement
>
> Vue CLI requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) version 8.9 or above (8.11.0+ recommended). You can manage multiple versions of Node on the same machine with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

The error indicates a syntax error for the `async` keyword, which is not supported in older versions of Node.

Comment: I will install node of 8.11 version

Comment: I will try and inform you. @tony19

Comment: @Kenneth The stack trace in the error message shows the `async` keyword usage is in Vue CLI itself.

Comment: I downloaded the node js from the link given by you and I installed it. But when I run node --version , I got v6.10.3. @tony19

Comment: How can I solve it? I uninstalled old node and reinstall again .Still I got same issue. @tony19

Comment: I downloaded node from https://nodejs.org/en/ and installed it. Then from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features , I uninstall it. @tony19

Comment: I uninstalled node but when i see the node version, it still show me the same version. @tony19

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows