# ng start angularProject or npm install makes extra files in root folder

Tags: angular, npm, ionic4, npm-install

I am in big trouble right now whenever i make new project using ng start new project or do npm install ,that project makes extra files in root folder like this.

[image]

my package.json file

```
 {
  "name": "angularProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

and i am using 
**node version:12.16.1 and npm version:6.13.4**

Please give me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution of this issue so if any body is facing this problem please try this solution.It's a node issue, your node didn't install properly so please follow this steps.

1. Uninstall from Programs & Features with the uninstaller.
2. Remove node related folder from your system,it may exist on below folder.

   `-C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs
   -C:\Program Files\Nodejs
   -C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (or %appdata%\npm)
   -C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (or %appdata%\npm-cache)
   -C:\Users\{User}\.npmrc (and possibly check for that without the . prefix too)
   -C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-*`
3. check your  **enviroment variable path** if you found any node related path please remove it.
4. restart/reboot your system.
5. if you still unable to remove node js to system [please check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

then install your node again and now you will not face this issue.