# Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\Peter.000\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''

Tags: npm

I have installed node 12.16.2

Unfortunately, when i run npm i am getting an error

I think this is due to some default user account issue occurred after i updated windows 10

Previously my user account was at C:\Users\Peter

after the windows 10 update it is now at C:\Users\Peter.000

I doubt that this has a direct connection to the error mentioned in the subject

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\Peter.000\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\Peter.000\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''
```

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information about the error, such as the stacktrace?

Comment: @Caramiriel error information included

Answer (score 6):

This problem is due to the wrong prefix which can be changed by finding `.npmrc` file present in `C:\Users\<your_account_name>`

Set it as

```
prefix="D:\\node\\node_global"
```

I hope your problem gets solved.

Comment: I need more upvotes for this answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install `npm-check-updates` and try again.

I was facing the same issue I resolve it with  these steps:

- `npm install -g npm-check-updates`  // It will update the npm
  dependencies. (*After that I checked my issue was resolved*)
- `npm install`  //It will update the dependencies and install the dependencies.

Hope It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create another windows account and run npm from there. However, still couldn't find out a way to run npm from my default windows user account (C:\Users\Peter.000)

[How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)
Helped me solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

open .nmrc file which is present in C:\Users<your_account_name> and change the prefix to C:\Users<your_account_name\AppData\Roaming\npm     (you can open .nmrc file with the help of vscode it worked for me).