# "npm install" installs unfamiliar files

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

So I am trying to run `npm install uuid` to add dependencies to package.json file. But instead, it gives me bunch of js files including uuid.cmd and uuid.ps1 files. The package.json also doesn't include uuid dependency.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGX29.png

Comment: Okay? And what is your *question*?

Comment: It's not true that it doesn't include dependencies. It's just that the uuid module has no dependencies

Comment: I am curious why `npm install` installs .cmd and .ps1 files for me. I am new to NPM, watched tutorials on youtube and they don't have those files. How do I fixt that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add node package to the  `package.json` file you need to add `--save` flag after the `npm install` command. So you can run below command in order to add `uuid` package to your package.json file.

```
 npm install uuid --save
```

`uuid` package already have bunch of different versions and make sure to use the correct version according to your requirement.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: I tried `npm install uuid --save` and it gave me the same result. No dependency added to package.json but added bunches of files I don't know like `uuid.cmd`and `uuid.ps1`. I also have this issue with laravel framework. `npm install` installs so many `.cmd`  and `.ps1` files.

Comment: try it by removing the existing node modules folder.

Comment: what are the npm and node version that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by completely uninstalled and reinstall Node.JS following this post

[How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)